# what are the Amazon SNS java API calls to check whether a phone number is blocked by the phone carrier or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

Can anyone tell me the Amazon SNS API call to check whether a phone number is blocked by the phone carrier or not?

I need to built an application which will check and let me know whether a phone number is currently premium locked by the phone carrier or not(phone carrier can send SMS to the phone number or not). And that status i need to use in other application.

Request you to help me on priority.

Comment: 2 upvotes? SO is going downhill fast

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloudwatch logs to lookup this information after trying to do the send. No way I know of to find that out before first attempting a send.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html